# Unit tests with attribute based routing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a controller with a routing attribute. This controller fails in a unit test because the route could not be found:

> A route named 'Values' could not be found in the route collection

This is the controller method:

```
[Route("api/values", Name="ApiValues")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{ 
    urlHelper.Link("ApiValues", new {});
}
```

This is my unit test:

```
var valuesController = new ValuesController()
{
    Request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost/api/")
    },
    Configuration = new HttpConfiguration()
};

valuesController.Get();
```

I also tried to add this to the unit test:

```
valuesController.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
valuesController.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
```

But that didn't help anything.

Comment: It is strange that I can't repro your issue. Everything works fine on my machine. What is the version of webapi you used? Have you provided with all your test code? I think the unit test won't run about the attribute routing part.

Comment: What is "urlHelper" in your controller action? Can you share full of it? Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got the same error:

```
A route named 'Values' could not be found in the route collection.
```

But the unit test passes on my machine after I add `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` and `EnsureInitialized`:

```
var valuesController = new ValuesController()
{
    Request = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost/api/") },
    Configuration = new HttpConfiguration()
};

valuesController.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
valuesController.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();

valuesController.Get();
```

Can you provide with more information to repro the issue or check whether there is any difference between our test code?

Comment: I've rechecked everything, because you saids it worked. And it works on my machine too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling the controller directly in the Unit tests, use Helper methods to get `Controller context` and `Action context`. This will avoid the use of

```
valuesController.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
valuesController.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
```

Refer the awesome explanation by Filip W. on [Testing routes in Web API 2](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/testing-routes-in-asp-net-web-api/)

Comment: In the attached post, there is a great effort in configuring the HttpConfiguration. Can this effort be saved by an axiomatic approach, namely, calling WebApiConfig.Register(testConfig) in the original project? This, however, assumes the correctness of WebapiConfig.Register. Hence the axiomatic approach